# Moisture issue in bathroom

Tags: bathroom, moisture

We just bought a house with only one bathroom and have found it to have an over abundance of moisture. There is a fan in the ceiling that comes on when you turn on the light and a window in the bathroom as well. I bought a "moisture collector" at Walmart that seems to be helping with the mold issue but the bath towels never completely dry and smell musty after only a few uses. What could be causing the problem?

Comment: Does the fan function properly? Do you run it 30-60 minutes after showers? Bath fans need to be cleaned regularly or the blades get so crudded up with lint that they don't push air. I take my fan unit out and clean it annually.

Comment: And, does the fan vent outside, or into the attic (and circuitously back into the rest of the house)? And, where are you located?

Answer (score 1):

Exhaust fans installed in older homes that have not been upgraded are often undersized. Check your existing unit to ensure it complies with the following advice from a major exhaust fan manufacturer:

> A good general rule for bathrooms with 8’ ceiling heights is to allow at least 1 cubic foot per minute (CFM) of ventilation for every square foot of room size for bathrooms under 100 square feet.For larger rooms, the recommendation is based on adding 50 CFM for each toilet, bathtub or shower and 100 CFM for jetted tubs.

You can usually find a sticker or placard with model # and rating on the housing, if you remove the fan grill/cover.

If it does not meet the quoted spec consider an upgrade. Also make sure your existing unit is properly ducted to the outside of your home and that the duct is not pinched or blocked.